# If the operator is linear but diverges on the basis vectors, how to find its matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the operator is linear, defined as an expression involving series but diverges on the basis vectors, how to find its matrix?

Comment: what you mean by "diverges on the basis vectors"?